# How to Use Variable Data in C# SQL Query String

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a project I'm working in, which I did not create. I am still relatively new to C# and ASP.NET as a whole. I am faced with this SQL query:

```
var sql = @"SELECT * FROM [database] WHERE [submitDate] >= Convert(datetime,'20130301')";

var sql = @"SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id)AS rowNum, * FROM [webDBs].[dbo].[employeeRecognition] WHERE [submitDate] >= Convert(datetime,'20130301')
) AS E
WHERE rowNum >= {0}
AND rowNum < {1}";
```

These of course behaves exactly as expected. What I need to do, however, is make the 2013 part of the `Convert(datetime,'20130301')` bit actually equal to the current yet, so that we don't have to update this query every single year.

Based on my limited experience I started by trying to concatenate in a C# variable, not only did that not work, but after some research I learned that method can be an opening for potential SQL Injections.

I read a bit about parameterizing the SQL Query, but everything I saw on that led me to believe that I would have to rewrite/rethink how this data is being pulled from the database in the first place.

Any advice on how to accomplish my goal?

Here's what I'm working with:

```
protected string RecordCount()
        {
            EmployeeRecognitionDataContext db = new EmployeeRecognitionDataContext();

            var sql = @"SELECT * FROM [database] WHERE [submitDate] >= Convert(datetime,'20130301')";

            var query = db.ExecuteQuery<employeeRecognition>(sql);

            //return "[{\"count\":\"" + query.Count() + "\"}]";
            return query.Count().ToString();
        }
```

Function the second `var` is being used in:

```
 protected string SelectRecords(int startIndex, int pageSize) {

            int rowNum = startIndex + pageSize;

            EmployeeRecognitionDataContext db = new EmployeeRecognitionDataContext();

            var sql = @"SELECT * FROM (
                        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id)AS rowNum, * FROM [database] WHERE [submitDate] >= Convert(datetime,'20130301')
                        ) AS E
                        WHERE rowNum >= {0} 
                        AND rowNum < {1}";

            var query = db.ExecuteQuery<employeeRecognition>(sql, startIndex, rowNum);

            List<Employee> eList = new List<Employee>();

            foreach (var employee in query)
            {
                eList.Add(new Employee { 
                    value = employee.id.ToString(),
                    firstName = employee.firstName, 
                    lastName = employee.lastName, 
                    department = employee.department,
                    drop = employee.shortAchievement, 
                    recognition = employee.longAchievement,
                    submitDate = employee.submitDate.ToString()
                });

            }

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

            return serializer.Serialize(eList);
        }
```

Comment: What problem are you having with parameters?  Parameters are the right way to do this.  (or do it all in SQL)

Comment: The problem starts with me not knowing how to properly add parameters to this particular string. The methods of doing so that I have found show `Parameter.Add` as methods that do not seem to work in this particular instance where the SQL Query is simply a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just change the code which generates that string. Something like;

```
   String.Format(@"SELECT * FROM [database] WHERE [submitDate] >= Convert(datetime,'{0}0301')", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());
```

Will make it so the string always has the current year there.

The docs for `String.Format` can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

It basically works like this. You call `String.Format` with the first argument being your string. Within that string, you put format specifiers (the `{0}` is a format specifier). Each instance of `{x}` is replaced with the corresponding argument. So, you can do something like this;

```
   string replacingThreeValues = String.Format("Replacing {0}, {1}, {2}", "one", "two", "three");
```

And it will result in `replaceingThreeValues == "Replacing one, two, three"`. So in your second example of `var sql = ...` you've put in some format specifiers, but you're not calling Format, also you're not passing any arguments to replace those values with. Instead you just get a string with the literal {0} and {1} in it. Only when you're calling `String.Format` and passing the appropriate arguments will those values be replaced with the arguments you pass it.

Comment: Thanks for stopping in. When I try to use this method I am met with the following error: `An object reference is required for the non static field...`

Comment: @TXChetG sorry I put in an edit, that should be `DateTime.Now.Year`, I was calling it like it was a static property when it's an instance property.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That at least doesn't cause a build error. It's claiming to return no records at this point which is fairly confusing, since it works just fine if I just use 2013.

Comment: @TXChetG it might still need the `ToString()` call. Look at what the string is in the debugger. If it's the same as the static string you're using then it's obv not the string.

Comment: I've made a huge mistake. Your suggestion is working very well at the moment. I had stupidly forgotten to replace [database] in your suggestion with my actual database name.

Comment: If you have the time, could you take a look at the second `var sql = ...` statement I added? I attempted to follow the example you set before to no avail.

Comment: @TXChetG yeah, I'll put in an edit explaining how to use `String.Format`, you're not using it correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the link. I can see now that a major issue is the way that the original `var` is written in the first place. I updated my original question with the function in it's entirety. If you're still available.

Comment: -1 for not using sql datetime parameter and re-enforcing unneccessary convert function call

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the rest of your code looks like but here's a possible example of using parameters.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("<connection string>"))
{
    var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM [database] WHERE [submitDate] >= @myDate";
    DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse("<date string>");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myDate", myDate);
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    /* etc. */
}
```

Comment: I added more to my original question to give you a better idea of what I'm facing. Your suggestion is the parametizing method I had seen earlier, but am not yet sure how to properly implement it.

Comment: Now that I see the rest of the picture, I don't think you really need parameters. You would have to overload the ExecuteQuery<T> method to accept a sql parameter.